# Getting content overlapped while having fixed navbar

Tags: css

I am trying to have a top text and navbar fixed at the top of the page and it should not scroll up with the content. I was able to fix it at the top by using position:fixed,but content is getting overlapped.

I used position: position:sticky, set margin and padding, but nothing helped.

I want to know how neatly I can achieve this. Please help

```css
* {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}

h1 {
    background-color: aquamarine;
}

.top {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}

.navbar {
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
}


.navbar a {
    color: wheat;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin: 2%;
}

p {
    font-size: 2rem;

}

h3,
h2 {
    font-size: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./home.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="top">
        <h1>John Doe</h1>
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-content">
                <a href="#about-me"> About Me</a>
                <a href="#projects">Projects</a>
                <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">

        <div id="about-me">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus repellat ullam dolore sequi sapiente
                eveniet a tempora dolorum porro inventore illo, maiores minus corporis. Facere mexcepturi corporis.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="projects">
            <h2>Project 1</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis voluptas accusamus ab eum iste, nihil
                laborum sit harum architecto laudantium odio, ratione totam quis qui quaerat suscipit corporis et rem.
            </p>
          </div>
        <div id="contact">
            <h2>Contact Info</h2>
            <h3>233443454354</h3>
            <h3>Address: abc, 1234</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you have dynamic content, then it best to use JS to calculate the content margin-top, if not, just set margin-top to fixed pixel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add padding top to your content:

```
#content {
 padding-top: 80px; /* height of your nav */
}
```